# Position: fixed element cut off by parent element overflow:hidden (IOS7, Mobile Safari)

Tags: html, responsive-design, mobile-safari, css

Mobile Safari in IOS7 seems to have an issue with the CSS visual format model- in a more complex use case.
Basically I want to show an element with position: fixed; inside of an element, that uses overflow: hidden. Since the **fixed** element should be put out of the parents viewport, the overflow should be ignored.

I've created a fiddle to show the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/6Tus7/10

If you watch this on Chrome, Firefox etc. you will see an yellow overlay that is not cut off by it's parents overflow rule (like expected).
In Mobile Safari you will see the yellow box have been cut off.

[image]

It's funny that it seems to work, if you put all this in an iframe again. I'am stuck on this and still hope, that i just made a simple mistake...

Thank you.

Here is a stack snipped taken from the jsfiddle:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#toggle-overlay").click(function() {
    $('#overlay').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wrap {
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#table-container {
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px hsla(220, 74%, 33%, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gray;
}

table {
  margin: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 104.382%;
  border: 0 none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

#overlay {
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="table-container">
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 40px;" />
        <col style="width: 144px;" />
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><span>col1</span></th>
          <th>
            <span>col2</span>
            <button id="toggle-overlay">Toggle Menu</button>
            <div id="overlay">
              <p>Hi! I'am a overlay. I'am set to positio fixed, so i should have my own viewpoint.</p>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem with Safari on Windows

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback @MladenJanjetović but isn't Safari for windows discontinued? I threw the latest installation in a VM and tested the fiddle and could not reproduce the problem I have with iOS

Comment: Nico, It is Win7, not mobile, but the same problem. I have element with position:fixed (some overlay tint with gallery) and grand parent with overflow:hidden. When I remove overflow:hidden, the overlay shows normaly like in all other modern browsers (Chrome, FF, IE)

Comment: yes i tested Win7 + Safrai with no problem on this fiddle. If you have another example i will test it. I think this boils down to be a browser bug.

Comment: Yes, your fiddle is ok. I have some more stuff nested in my markup, but still, fixed should be put out of the parent layer. Right? No matter what it's parents have of CSS rules

Comment: absolutly. fixed elements must have a own viewport.

Comment: same issue here. How do you fixed it in the end?

Comment: same issue, anyone got it right?

Comment: 8 years later, I still have the same problem haha. Does somebody knows how to fix this?